# What to do when comments on an answer show the answer is a bad one?

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

I answer a question, but then someone comments on my answer showing that it's a bad answer, possibly presenting a better answer. The comments might be quite informative, but the answer is still bad or worse wrong. Should I delete my answer (losing the valuable comments) or edit the answer to summarise the comments? What if I see this in someone else's answer?

Worst case scenario: What if I come across an accepted answer I know is bad / wrong?

Comment: For your worst case : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56252/how-to-handle-accepted-bad-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your answer edit it to remove the incorrect information and (hopefully) improve it. You can ping the commentator using the `@username` syntax to show that you've taken on board what they've said. If they down-voted your answer then they might even remove the down-vote.

If your answer can't be recovered then just delete it.

In the case of someone else's answer if there are already comments pointing out the mistake(s) and there's no indication of them being corrected (no edit history for example) then down-vote it if you think it's particularly bad. You might want to bookmark it so you can see if the problem gets fixed at some point.